# Avoid system Display Size effect my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, size

I have already ignored system font size adding this to my Material App:

```
builder: (context, child) {
    final MediaQueryData data = MediaQuery.of(context);

    return MediaQuery(
      data: data.copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
      child: child,
    );
  },
```

But now I would like to "ignore" also the system display size. In fact if it's set for example to "Large" inside the app everything is resized.

Comment: please look at this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil

Comment: what is "system display size"? Could you please show some screenshots demonstrating what system settings you have changed, and what is the result of a Flutter app?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the specific setting "system display size", and about the effect of that setting on the app? By giving us more context maybe someone could provide a solution or a workaround

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html . Put it as an ancestor of the widget tree to resize your whole widget tree.

May need to pass extra box constraints to the child widget of Transform if your children widget tree behaves abnormally.

Comment: why vote down? Transform does solve the problem. Please give some comments if you think it does not solve the problem

Comment: vote downs are because your response is not related to the problem. 
You're talking about specific widgets, this is regarding the whole application and the effect that changing a value in the Android device setting has on how the app is shown.